# How to fix Prestashop Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler?

Tags: smarty, prestashop, fatal-error, prestashop-1.6

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template "/home/sites/riversoft.com.mk/public_html/admin397ebpwvj/themes/default/template/header.tpl" on line 256 "headers: {"cache-control": "no-cache"}," - Unexpected ": ", expected one of: "}" <-- thrown in /home/sites/riversoft.com.mk/public_html/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 256

Comment: Some context here would he helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the /home/sites/riversoft.com.mk/public_html/admin397ebpwvj/themes/default/template/header.tpl either remove `headers: {"cache-control": "no-cache"}` or enclose it in {literal} like this:

```
{literal}headers: {"cache-control": "no-cache"}{/literal}
```